# Rails + Devise: Redirect to User resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When my `application_controller.rb` redirects to `users_path` like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    users_path
end
```

the redirect works. But if I change it to `user_path`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path
end
```

I get a routing error. Here is my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
get "users/show"

resources :orders

resources :users do
    resources :orders
end
```

I thought maybe I should pass the userID like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    user_path(@user)
end
```

but the error comes back `Couldn't find User without an ID`. Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should try `current_user` after login

```
user_path(current_user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent several hours trying to get the same functionality, and this is the code in the ApplicationController that ended up working for me:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    current_user
end
```

If I ever tried `current_user_path`, I always got `undefined local variable or method current_user_path` errors.

Also, I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Devise 2.1.2.

Hope that helps.